# Imagem WhatsApp, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quando copio a URL do meu site no WhatsApp, ele não gera a miniatura da imagem/noticia.

Em outros sites aparece, queria entender qual código devo usar para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

O WhatsApp usa as mesmas tags (og:tags, [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/)) do Facebook para renderizar o conteúdo, com algumas restrições extras que parecem não ser muito bem documentadas (parece que a imagem só pode ter no máximo 300kb, por exemplo).

Veja se aparece tudo normalmente com a ferramenta do Facebook e depois faça os ajustes testando no WhatsApp: [Depurador de compartilhamento](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=pt.stackoverflow.com)